# Can not add plug in for MAven in Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to add plug in for Maven in Eclipse Helios (64 bit) on SLES 11. When I open Help -> Install new software and try to add url "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/release". It gives me following error

"unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/release"

I have also tried to uncheck the option "Contact all update sites " and checking the proxy settings from General -> preferences -> Network Connection as well and the proxy settings  seems ok.

Any idea whats going wrong ? In eclipse, I am not able to open Eclipse MArketplace and url in internal browser of eclipse. It seems that eclipse is not connecting to internet at all.

Comment: Are you bound to using Helios? If not, consider switching to Kepler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply have the wrong link. The correct one is http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases (missed the `s`) (Source: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Integration). Also, unless you are forced to use Helios, consider updating Eclipse to the Kepler release.

Comment: I had the same problem with Kepler also..I typed the correct url (with "releases") but it still does not work. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try to Configure your eclipse.ini with argument **-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true**

Starting eclipse with this arg works for me